# Store collection of strings with EF in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

**Details**

I work on a `ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0` project.
I have a topic MVC object, where I store that ID of the User that's created the topic and would like to store Users who can edit this topic.

Logically I should store the IDs of the Users who can edit the topic.

This is the problem.

**Question**

How could I store user IDs that are strings with mapping to EF?
**Can't store** `List<string>` or `string[]`, because EF can not map these type of collections.

Example user id: a77-95471b9f597d (btw. this is the default `ApplicationUser` of a ASP.NET project.)

Also : One User can have more Topic IDs and one Topic could have more User IDs

I've already thought that store all IDs in a simple string, split them with any kind of symbol(eg.: semicolon), but there comes a question: How long a simple string could be and there I had an answer I've read:

> This is one of those situations where ["If you have to ask, you're
>   probably doing something wrong."] is the case.

Comment: You could make user groups and have specific groups be able to edit topics and then simply add the ids of users to those groups.

Comment: I've already read something about `role-based authorization` is ASP.NET, but you think something else right?

Comment: I accept any answer that can help me, I really have no idea how to achieve the above problem.

Comment: I put an EF relational solution below.  The group suggestion would make maintenance easier for sure, but I'm starting simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snarky and unhelpful, but accurate.  This is a typical m:m scenario.

```
public class Topic {
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    // other topic stuff
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Collaboration> Collaborators { get; set; }
}

public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    // other user stuff
    public virtual ICollection<Collaboration> Collaborators { get; set; }
}

public class Collaboration {
    public int CollaborationId { get; set; }
    // other stuff dependent on topic + user
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
}
```

All users who can edit (collaborate) a Topic. db = EF context

```
db.Topics.Include("Collaborators").Include("Collaboration.User").FirstOrDefault(p => p.TopicId == <key value>);
```

All topics a user can edit

```
db.Users.Include("Collaborators").Include("Collaboration.Topic").FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserId == <key value>);
```

THAT's a relational model.  Collaboration is the "join table" for the relationship between Topics and Users.  There is one record in Collaboration for each intersection of a Topic and a User.  And in Topic, there is also an Owner (single User) which is the 1:m of Owners to Topics.

Comment: It's a n:m (Many-to-Many) relationship, not a One-to-Many

Comment: Collaboration is the join table of a m:m relationship.  Fixed post.